# lex start conditions

Tags: text-processing

I'm working with a 40-year-old lex program that has statements like

```
  BEGIN PROGRAM + 1;
```

I understand what

```
BEGIN PROGRAM
```

does, but what is the intention of the `+ 1`?  Does it skip the first rule in the `<PROGRAM>` context?  The generated code suggests not, but I haven't dug into it too deeply.  Does it select the context listed after the `<PROGRAM>` context?  That seems slightly more plausible, but a test lex program doesn't support that intention (it's likely the test program is ineffectively written).  I'm using flex, not a 40-year-old version of lex.

For completeness, here's the test program:

```
$ cat t.lex 
%s A B C

%%
                BEGIN A;

<A>[BC]         if (yytext[0] == 'B') BEGIN B + 1; else BEGIN C;
<A>.            printf("A: '%c'\n", yytext[0]);

<B>[AC]         if (yytext[0] == 'A') BEGIN A; else BEGIN C;
<B>.            printf("B: '%c'\n", yytext[0]);

<C>[AB]         if (yytext[0] == 'A') BEGIN A; else BEGIN B;
<C>.            printf("C: '%c'\n", yytext[0]);

%%

main() { yylex(); }

$ echo abcBabc | ./a.out 
A: 'a'
A: 'b'
A: 'c'
B: 'a'
B: 'b'
B: 'c'

$
```

Answer (score 1):

In a lex program, you can have *start conditions*, which are defined by a **`%s`** directive like this:

```
%s PROGRAM COMMENT WHATEVER
```

and then switch between those using the **`BEGIN`** macro.  In a quick check, flex numbers those consecutively starting at 1 (because the predefined **`INITIAL`** state is **`0`**).

Running flex, you would see in `lex.yy.c` some lines like this:

```
#define INITIAL 0
#define PROGRAM 1
#define COMMENT 2
#define WHATEVER 3
```

The ostensible programmer for your example decided to hard-code a **`1`** rather than use the symbol.

Comment: Well, that's the itch, because in the *original* lex the start conditions are incremented by 2, not by 1, as in flex; `%s foo bar` will define `foo` as `1`, `bar` as `3`, etc. `BEGIN PROGRAM + 1` should set the state to an anonymous one equal to `PROGRAM + 1`. I don't think that would work in flex, even if it's changed to `BEGIN(PROGRAM + 1)`.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  `BEGIN` is a macro that expands into `(yy_start) = 1 + 2 *` (again, this is flex-generated, but there's a comment pointing out this is how lex does it).  If the definition was `#define BEGIN(_s) (yy_start) = 1 +2*(_s)`, then this answer makes sense, but it expands into `(yy_start) = 1 + 2 * PROGRAM + 1`, which makes `yy_start` an even number when it appears it's supposed to be odd.  The intention behind such a calculation is still open.

Comment: @UncleBilly Ah, so you're saying that flex keeps the form of the BEGIN macro, but the expansion has been changed from the original lex.  Which implies that, in original lex, `BEGIN PROGRAM + 1` would indeed switch to `COMMENT`, to use Thomas DIcky's example.  Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @UncleBilly Which means my interpretation of `BEGIN PROGRAM + 1` as moving to `COMMENT` is wrong because `PROGRAM` is 2, `COMMENT` is 4 and `PROGRAM + 1` is somewhere in between.  Ugh, I was hoping this was a well-known idiom that subsided into obscurity.  Thanks for your help.